# How to describe sets derived from same superset in ordinary language?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do we describe two related sets in comparative terms? For example, S1({{x}, {x}} : x ∈ N) and S2({{x}, {x}} : x ∈ N : 0 less than x less than 5)? Do we say that we have imposed a set rule (or set exclusion - not sure what 0 less than x less than 5 is called) on S2 such that S2 is a proper subset of S1 such that it is a set of ordered pairs whose domain and range are both limited to (0,5)? And, do we use the term related sets since that can be confusing with relations? Or, would the term similar sets be better?

Comment: Correct : $S_2$ is a *proper* subset of $S_1$ because you have used into the definition of $S_2$ a "specifying condition" (the formula : $x \in \mathbb N \land 0 < x < 5$)which is more "restrictive" than the one used in $S_1$ (which is only : $x \in \mathbb N$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to describe $S_2$ as a proper subset of set $S_1$.

Every element in $S_2$ is an element of $S_1$, but not vice-versa. So we have $\;S_2\subsetneq S_1$, or alternatively: $S_2 \subset S_1$ and $S_2 \neq S_1$.

In "ordinary" language, we can say that $S_2$ is contained in $S_1$, but $S_1$ is not contained in $S_2$.

The added condition (restriction) that $x$ must meet in $S_2$ is equivalent to specifying $x \in  \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.

So while $S_1$ is infinite, $S_2$ is finite, given the conditions $x \in \mathbb N$ and $0 \lt x \lt 5$. (Indeed, $S_2$ is the set of exactly $16$ ordered pairs.) So we can further describe the relationship by stating that $S_2$ is a finite subset of $S_1$.